# List view with files getting from Google Drive + Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, view

how can I get files from a Google Drive folder and show it like a view in sharepoint?It is this possible? I was looking for hours but I couldn't find nothing. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is a 3rd party tool, have not tried it though: https://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/Google%20Edition/002_HowTo/003_HowToMigrateGoogleDrive/004_MigrateFolderAsDocLib.htm

Comment: Oh! I saw it! but i didn't understand how to use it, I will  read it again